# Confused by NVIDIA's vulkan tip

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I've recently started to learn vulkan and there are unclear things for me like command buffers. AFAIK I should have command buffer for each swap chain image and reuse it each frame with ONE_TIME_SUBMIT flag, but I've found NVIDIA's article which states don't do that (if I get it right). What should I do then? Recreate command buffer each frame? I would be glad If someone could clarify that. Thanks.

The article: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/vulkan-dos-donts/

The statement (Under Don'ts in Work Submission section):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzczu.png)

Comment: You mean the `Don’t design around lots of command buffer reuse...` one? I think it's just a matter of pragmatism, many demos use an approach where N command buffers are created and never change. Trying to stretch that approach into a fully dynamic world can be impractical. You're often better off focusing on other techniques (e.g. draw call batching, frustum culling, multithreading) to optimize. Even if you don't put much effort in, Vulkan drivers are often fast at generating command buffers anyway (relative to OpenGL) so pre-recording often isn't great bang for your buck.

Comment: Doesn't the `ONE_TIME_SUBMIT` flag mean that you are going to *not* reuse the buffer, and instead re-record it?

Comment: @user369070 I think they mean not to reuse the recording. It is probably fine to reuse cmdbuff **objects** when there are no sync complications.

Comment: @Columbo Thank you! Maybe I was confused because I misunderstood the word "reuse". I thought "reuse" means "re-record" so I couldn't get what's wrong with this approach.